# Does SQL Server guarantee data integrity?

Tags: sql-server

Simple question: does SQL Server provide any kind of record level checksum etc to guarantee that data in = data out? Or is this something that should be implemented at the application level with CRC/MD5?

**Edit 1:** I'm not talking about referential integrity, data range validation, or anything else like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can configure three modes for page data integrity through the [`PAGE_VERIFY` option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb402873.aspx).

See for instance [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/29/enabling-checksum-in-sql2005.aspx) about page verification options.

Comment: Not quite record level then, but probably good enough. Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you do get data corruption it is unlikely to affect just one record. The page granularity seems like a good fit IMHO. Combine this with ECC memory and the likelyhood of undetected data corruption is very low.